# In jquery code want to sum all Data by column wise except first row. how can i acheive it by following code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used following code to calculate sum.

```
$(".income_table tr:last td:not(:first,:nth-child(2),:nth-child(3))").text(function(i) {
    var t = 0;
    $(this).parent().prevAll().find("td:nth-child("+(i + 4)+")").each(function() {
        t += parseInt( $(this).text(), 10 ) || 0;
    });
    return t;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method to skip first row. The magic is that prevAll() gives you all predecessors in reverse order.

Check this:

```
$(".income_table tr:last td:not(:first,:nth-child(2),:nth-child(3))").text(function(i) {
    var t = 0;
    $(this).parent().prevAll().slice(0, -1).find("td:nth-child("+4+")").each(function() {
        t += parseInt(  $(this).text(), 10 ) || 0;
    });
    return t;
});
```

I've changed the second row in function to search exactly 4th column.

Try out:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yedc3dn3/16/)